# Django Rest Auth password reset link contains html codes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django REST-Auth for user registration. All works fine except for the fact that the password reset link contains `"%20"` and `"%0A"` html codes which yield the token not usable without manually adjusting it before POST. Sample link from the email received:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset/confirm/MTY0MjM0MGMtNGEyMi00ZmY5LWE3YzgtNDdiOGM2M2ViYzIy/%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205d9-2e76cc7a3bc99cf6f1ed/
```

I've tried overriding the PasswordResetSerializer etc. but nothing so far has helped to resolve the issue. Package versions as follows.

```
Django                         3.0.2     
django-rest-auth               0.9.5     
djangorestframework            3.11.0
```

Anyone know where this is coming from and how to fix it?

Comment: in the web spaces will convert to %20

Comment: Thanks, this is clear. But where do these whitespaces come from, what part of the rest auth sets them into the link?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your urls_patterns = [] is not correct for this view.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the url pattern as far as I can see. I switched to another auth framework. Problem solved.